# How to add student to student group

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have no idea how to add student to student group my code look like this:

Models:

Group

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Groups extends BaseEntitity {


    @Column(name = "group_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String GroupName;
```

Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends BaseEntitity{



@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 35)
private String name;

@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
private String last_name;

@Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
private String birth_date;

@Column(name = "city", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String city;
```

Students groups:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_group")
public class StudentGroup extends  BaseEntitity {
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_student", nullable = false)
private Student student;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_group", nullable = false)
private Group group;
```

I want to add student to group by click for button next to the student, go to page with groups and by click button next to selected group add selected student earlier in to this group like this:

```
<td>${student.birthDate}</td>
                        <td>${student.city}</td>

                        <td> <a href="${goToGroupURL}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Group</a></td>

<c:forEach items="${groupList}" var="group">
                <tr>
                    <td>${group.id}</td>
                    <td>${group.GroupName}</td>
                    <td> <a href="${addGroupURL}/${group.id}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Group</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class AddGroupServiceImpl implements AddGroupService {
@Autowired
private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

@Autowired
private GroupDAO groupDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public void addStudentToGroup(Student student, Group Group) {
    StudentGRoup studentGroup = new StudentGroup(student, group);

    studentGroupDAO.save(studentGroup);
    groupDAO.save(group);
```

Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/add-student/group/{groupId}")
public String createStudentGroup(@PathVariable Long groupId, Lond studentId, Principal principal, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {



    Group group = groupDao.findOne(groupId);
    Student student = studentDao.findOne(studentId);



    addGroupService.addStudentToGroup(student, group);
```

StudentGroupDAO:

```
@Repository public interface StudentGroupDAO extends JpaRepository<StudentGroup, Long> { }
```

I don't know how to do this in the controller and jsp someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

In general the concept seems fine. The problem is that you are passing detached entities to the persistence provider to save.

Try passing the ids to the transactional service and performing the queries there:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addStudentToGroup(Integer studentId, Integer groupId) {
    Group group = groupDao.findOne(groupId);
    Student student = studentDao.findOne(studentId);

    StudentGrupa studentGrupa = new StudentGrupa(student, grupy);

    studentGroupDAO.save(studentGroup);
    groupDAO.save(group);
}
```

Not sure what is going on inside `studentGroupDAO.save` but now your will be saving managed entities.

Comment: Do the findOne methods produce non-null result? Also do you get any error? or just the changes are not reflected in the database?

Comment: I don't know how to create controller, I do service like you said, but now my controller look like this: @RequestMapping( value = "/add-student/group/{groupId}" )
    public String AddStudentToGroup() {

       addGroupService.addStudentToGroup();
    }

Comment: addGroupService.addStudentToGroup(here id's); but i want to choose this student and group from jsp so how choose this id's at jsp?